# Is it possible to join a local windows machine (on premises) to an EC2 Windows Server Active Directory that is hosted on AWS?

Tags: active-directory, windows-server, windows-server-2022

I setup microsoft active directory on AWS EC2 Windows server and now i want to connect this AD to our local(on premises) windows machines, so is it possible or not and tell me the other solution?

Thanks

I have tried to connect with the domain name of AD to our local mwindows machine but its not connected.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have both, Domain Controller and Windows clients on the same network. I made a VPN server (OpenVPN is free), generated the .ovpn keys for the clients, and connected the client to the VPN. Once both are in the same network, your client should be able to reach the DC, then you can add it to the domain.